# How do I view my Swagger docs when using SwaggerWcf?

Tags: wcf, swagger, swagger-wcf

I'm trying to use [swaggerwcf](https://github.com/abelsilva/swaggerwcf/) to add Swagger to my WCF REST API.

I've followed the instructions, but I don't know what URL to use to view my Swagger documentation. I've tried:

http://myservername/api-docs

http://myservername/api-docs/index.html

http://myservername/api-docs/swagger.json

These all result in "Request Error", "The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service."

Answer (score 3):

It dependents on what code you have written in global.asax.

For example, my code in global.asax is

```
  protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("RegistrationService/api-docs", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(SwaggerWcfEndpoint)));
    }
```

Then I should visit http://localhost:62193/RegistrationService/api-docs  (http://localhost:62193 is my root path).

Also, please ensure you have configured web.xml.

```
  <service name="SwaggerWcf.SwaggerWcfEndpoint">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SwaggerWcf.ISwaggerWcfEndpoint"></endpoint>
  </service>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>


<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Then if you input http://localhost:62193/RegistrationService/api-docs/, it will redirect you to  http://localhost:62193/RegistrationService/api-docs/index.html?url=/RegistrationService/api-docs/swagger.json#!/Books/Service_BookStore_ReadBooks

Below is the result.
[image]

Comment: Excellent - I was missing <service name="SwaggerWcf.SwaggerWcfEndpoint"> - this is not required in some type of projects esp earlier ones but needed nowadays! wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

Still its not displaying method info on swagger